# BCP failing due to NULL

Tags: sql, syntax, bcp

I am trying to BCP a txt file to Azure.
The problem is when I have a null value, it writes the word NULL to the txt file.

How do I get around this as it causes errors when I try to BCP because it is trying to write NULL to numeric and GUID fields.

Comment: Show us the command you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert the base text file to remove the NULLS.

ISNULL(CAST(NullField AS VARCHAR(50)), '') AS NullField

This is a huge pain in the butt in tables with a lot of columns, so if there is an easier way, by all means share.

Answer (score 0):

When a value is NULL, simply leave the content empty instead of writing NULL. Here is an example:

```
Data to write = 34,45,23,12,NULL,21,67
txt file = 34,45,23,12,,21,67
```

Hope this will help you to solve your problem.

Comment: The problem is when it writes the file, it automatically writes the word NULL to the file. Tried finding and replacing and it appeared to kill the TAB delimiter on the file and this is also impractical since I am dealing with several million records in the file.

Comment: You have no possibility to modify the writing process in order to change that? It will be useful if you can provide us a sample of the file content and the command you're using for the BCP (also the format file if you use one).

Comment: In Query Analyzer, when you write to a file, I do not believe there is a way to suppress the word NULL for a null value.
It is a text file that is tab delimited.
the BCP command is
BCP MyDb.dbo.MyTable IN C:\myfile.txt -c -t\t -r\n -k -U username -S   servername -P password   It fails with or without the -k